# How do I deserialize timestamps that are in milliseconds with Jackson?

Tags: java, groovy, jackson

I've got some JSON that has timestamps in milliseconds:

```
{"foo":"bar","timestamp":1386280997}
```

Asking Jackson to deserialize this into an object with a DateTime field for the timestamp results in `1970-01-17T01:11:25.983Z`, a time shortly after the epoch because Jackson is assuming it to be in *nanoseconds*.  Aside from ripping apart the JSON and adding some zeros, how might I get Jackson to understand the millisecond timestamp?

Edit—some test code that shows this (Groovy syntax):

```
class TimestampThing {
    DateTime timestamp

    @JsonCreator
    public TimestampThing(@JsonProperty('timestamp') DateTime timestamp) {
      this.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

And a couple of tests, the first in milliseconds, the second in microseconds:

```
class TimestampTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()

    void testMillisecondTimestamp() {
        String json = '{"timestamp":1386280997}'
        TimestampThing thing = mapper.readValue(json, TimestampThing.class)
        println thing.getTimestamp()
    }

    void testNanosecondTimestamp() {
        String json = '{"timestamp":1386280997000}'
        TimestampThing thing = mapper.readValue(json, TimestampThing.class)
        println thing.getTimestamp()
    }
}
```

The out from running the test class is:

```
1970-01-16T20:04:40.997-05:00
2013-12-05T17:03:17.000-05:00
```

Comment: Deserializing JSON dates: "Numeric (integer) serializations are recognized, assumed to be in Unix timestamp notation (milliseconds since epoch, Jan 1st 1970 GMT)" -[Jackson FAQ Date Handling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling). It doesn't mention nanosecond in there. In fact, `console.log(new Date().getTime())` will show that your timestamp is off by a factor of 1000 in the wrong direction. In other words, that is *seconds* since epoch.

Comment: I see your skepticism from reading the FAQ…so I wrote some test code as simple as possible that illustrates the problem for me on Java 1.7.0_21 with Jackson 2.3.0 and Joda Time 2.3

Comment: Whoops!  I was off by a few orders of magnitude—the timestamps that I have are in _seconds_ (i.e. Unix timestamps) not _milliseconds_ as I had claimed.  So Jackson is indeed doing the correct thing and in line with its documentation.  I created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635698/how-do-i-deserialize-timestamps-that-are-in-seconds-with-jackson) to figure out how to get Jackson to understand my _seconds_ timestamps.