# How do I deserialize timestamps that are in seconds with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, timestamp, jackson, unix-timestamp

I've got some JSON that has timestamps in seconds (i.e. a Unix timestamp):

```
{"foo":"bar","timestamp":1386280997}
```

Asking Jackson to deserialize this into an object with a DateTime field for the timestamp results in `1970-01-17T01:11:25.983Z`, a time shortly after the epoch because Jackson is assuming it to be in *milliseconds*.  Aside from ripping apart the JSON and adding some zeros, how might I get Jackson to understand the *seconds* timestamp?

Comment: There's a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/jackson-date-deserialization) that shows how to implement a custom date deserialization class

Comment: Thanks for the tip—I answered the question with the details of how I solved this issue since the deserializer is a bit different from that question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I wrote a custom [deserializer](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) to handle timestamps in seconds (Groovy syntax).

```
class UnixTimestampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnixTimestampDeserializer.class)

    @Override
    DateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String timestamp = jp.getText().trim()

        try {
            return new DateTime(Long.valueOf(timestamp + '000'))
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            logger.warn('Unable to deserialize timestamp: ' + timestamp, e)
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

And then I annotated my POGO to use that for the timestamp:

```
class TimestampThing {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = UnixTimestampDeserializer.class)
    DateTime timestamp

    @JsonCreator
    public TimestampThing(@JsonProperty('timestamp') DateTime timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, just out of curiousity what dialect of Java is it? Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm in ordinary boring java, too. Just use the Annotation on whatever DateTime field you need. Did not try using Java 8 Date, but should be no problem there either. Thanks

Comment: If you can use java8 you're maybe interested in using `java.time.Instant` class and to use regular jackson [datatypes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/). This way you just need
`@JsonProperty("timestamp") private Instant timestamp`

Comment: @Pierrick Please turn this into an answer, so I can upvote ;-)

Comment: @Pierrick I am using `java.time.Instant`, and Jackson still treats timestamps as milliseconds.

Answer (score 16):

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="s")
public Date timestamp;
```

**edit**: vivek-kothari suggestion

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, pattern="s")
public Timestamp timestamp;
```

Comment: why downvote? because it is easier than other solutions?

Comment: probably because its timestamps are represented as `integer` and not as `string` in json.

Comment: jackson does required type conversion

Comment: `{"timestamp" : "42"}` is not the same as `{"timestamp" : 42}`, and I'm assuming that your `JsonFormat` will expect double quotes around.

Comment: looks like jackson does automatic type conversion using the field type and not the intermediate data type used by formatter

Comment: This does not work, because it {{s}} mean not the seconds since 1970, it mean the seconds of the "given" date (0..59)

Comment: I used `NUMBER_INT` instead of `NUMBER` to get rid of decimal places - so in full: `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT, pattern="s")`

Comment: This only works with java.sql.Timestamp, there is no way to make it work with java.util.Date if your json contains number

Answer (score 14):

A very similar approach to that of @DrewStephens's which uses the Java SE `TimeUnit` API (introduced in `JDK1.5`) instead of plain String concatenation and is thus (arguably) a little bit cleaner and more expressive:

```
public class UnixTimestampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String unixTimestamp = parser.getText().trim();
        return new Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(Long.valueOf(unixTimestamp)));
    }
}
```

Specifying your custom deserializer (`UnixTimestampDeserializer`) on the affected `Date` field(s):

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = UnixTimestampDeserializer.class)
private Date updatedAt;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue, except my ZonedDateTime objects got turned to unix-timestamps (seconds) and I needed them in milliseconds (to initialize JS Date objects on the browser).

Implementing a custom serializer/deserializer looked like too much work for something that should be pretty straightforward, so I looked elsewhere and found that I can just configure the object mapper for the desired result.

Because my application already overrides the default ObjectMapper provided by Jersey, I just had to disable [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS).

Here's my code

```
@Provider
public class RPObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public RPObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // this turned ZonedDateTime objects to proper seconds timestamps 
        defaultObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        // disable to serialize dates for millis timestamps
        defaultObjectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

        // using Java8 date time classes
        defaultObjectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }
}
```

And that's it